# Add post-build script to next.js on Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

Is this supported somehow? I'd like to execute arbitrary code to post-process the built HTML/css/etc after next.js does its thing.

Comment: Does a `postbuild` command work in your package.json? Maybe test something simple like echoing a value at first. You can also have a custom build command, so you could simply run `yarn run build && your-custom-script`

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion worked if you want to add it as an answer.

Comment: Done, and did you try the `postbuild` thing? The limitation is that it would run on your local builds as well which can become annoying during dev.

Comment: postbuild somehow doesn't get triggered by vercel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom build command in Vercel, that does both the build and the postbuild: `yarn run build && yarn run your-postbuild-script`.

[Documentation here](https://vercel.com/docs/build-step).

Comment: I'm looking to run an external script after Vercel finishes building and deploying in prod. Your current solution would just run them one after the other?

Comment: So your question is not about post-build, but about post-deploy, which is another issue. I don't know how to solve this, I'd be tempted to trigger the script post-build and add a kind of timer to wait for the website to be probably ready (like build + 5 minutes shoud be enough to deploy). I don't know about detecting a successful deploy.

Comment: The above works post-deploy as well.